# Kotlin - Compare values between common fields of two classes

Tags: kotlin

I have two classes that share almost all the same properties.

```
data class UserDetailsDTO( username: String?, id: UUID, lastName: String? ..)
data class UserDetailsInput( username: String?, id: UUID, lastName: String?..)
```

And I have two variables of the same classes, with populated properties.

```
 val result = method that returns type UserDetailsDTO
 val update = UserDetailsInput type
```

I need to do this:

compare update to result, keep only the fields in update that are different from result and not null.

How can I achieve that ?
I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What about fields in UserDetailsInput which do not exist in UserDetailsDTO, should they also be returned?

Comment: `keep only the fields in update that are different from result and not null.` What about those which are not different? They should become null? Also you are using non-nullable types in UserDetailsDTO, so they will never be null.

Comment: @lukas.j there are no such fields in the current implementation (because one of them is the output of the fields in the database, the other one is the input to change some of those fields) , but if they were they should be returned yes.

Comment: @ArpitShukla They are all nullable. I have written it here wrong.
Those whose values are the same should be skipped.
Example: Input username is different from result username, keep that in the final variable.
Input lastName is the same from result lastName, skip that.
input category is null, skip that.

Comment: What do you mean by `skip` here? What data type do you want at the end for the result?

Comment: The end result should be an object with only the fields that are different from result and not null in the input variable.

Comment: What kind of object? A Map?

Comment: @lukas.j Yes, a map would be ideal.

Comment: If you want the result in a map, you will have to compare each element in `result` and `update` one by one and fill the map. Like `if(result.username != update.username) map["username"] = result.username` Do this for all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extention function like this:

```
 fun UserDetailsInput.uniqueValue(UserDetailsDTO: UserDetailsInput) {
            id = if (id != UserDetailsDTO.id) UserDetailsDTO.id else id
            username = if (username != UserDetailsDTO.username) UserDetailsDTO.username else username
            lastName = if (lastName != UserDetailsDTO.lastName) UserDetailsDTO.lastName else lastName
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Would I have to check for every input field or is there a generic way to check for all ? Because there are 9-10 fields, I only added two in the example above to abstract the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create an utility method witch take them both and return a UserDetailsDTO with only the diff

(I never did kotlin but i think it's something like that )

```kotlin
Class TestDTO(){
    
    public String name;
    
    public  Int age;
    
}

Class TestInput(){
    
    public String name;
    
    public  Int age;
    
}


fun TestDiff(testDTO: TestDTO,testInput : TestInput ){
    
    finalDTO = new TestDTO();
    
    if(testInput.name != null && testInput.name != testDTO.name){
       finalDTO.name =  testInput.name;
    }
    
    if(testInput.age != null && testInput.age != testDTO.age){
        finalDTO.age =  testInput.age;
    }
    
    return finalDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant. Uses reflection to check which field of *UserDetailsInput* exists also in the target class *UserDetailsDTO*:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

data class UserDetailsDTO(
  val username: String?,
  val id: UUID,
  val lastName: String?
)

data class UserDetailsInput(
  val username: String?,
  val id: UUID,
  val lastName: String?,
  val firstName: String?
)

val result = UserDetailsDTO("User 1", UUID.randomUUID(), "Abc")
val input = UserDetailsInput("User 1", result.id, null, "Super")

val mapOfDifferenValues = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()

val propsInResult = UserDetailsDTO::class.memberProperties
val propsInInput = UserDetailsInput::class.memberProperties

for (propInInput in propsInInput) {
  // Value from Input
  val valueFromInput = propInInput.get(input)
  // Check if it is not null
  if (valueFromInput != null) {
    // Check if a field with same name exists in 'result' class
    if (propInInput.name in propsInResult.map { it.name }) {
      // A field with same name exists in result class, so check if it has the same value
      if (valueFromInput != propsInResult.first { it.name == propInInput.name }.get(result)) {
        // It does not have the same value, so add it to the map
        mapOfDifferenValues[propInInput.name] = valueFromInput
      }
    } else {
      // There is no field with the same name in 'result' class, so add it to the map
      mapOfDifferenValues[propInInput.name] = valueFromInput
    }
  }
}

println(mapOfDifferenValues)
```